# Illustrator 2014 - How to remove/move "share on behance" from Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, interface-design, creative-cloud, behance

It's really annoying when you try to click on export and you accidentally click on behance. Especially when you're busy doing real work.

Is there anyway to get rid of it?

Or is there a way to move it somewhere else where you can't accidentally click on it?

Edit: It's just a part of Illustrator. I don't have a behance account. It is still there even when you install a demo of Illustrator on a new computer.

[image]

Comment: I do not have that menu item here... I've never been a Behance user.. there **is** an option in your Creative Cloud account to link to Behance. But then.. I **also** don't have the "Save for Microsoft Office" item in that location either in CC2018 -- it's there in CS6 though. It appears you *may be* using an older version of Illustrator.

Comment: @Scott I see it's been removed in Illustrator 2017 also. I'm using 2014 I should have mentioned that.

Comment: Altough you have not installed it, It still can be a plugin, installed by Adobe. Search Illustrator plugins in your computer. One of them can be Behance.

Comment: Honestly think it's in the CC app manager.. a check box under "Assets"-- I can't confirm that at the moment.. my CC manager needs me to reboot and I can't right now.

Comment: @Scott I'm actually poking around in the program "plug-ins" now. I'm making a complete copy of Illustrator incase I break something XD

Comment: @Scott it had nothing to do with plugins. Deleting the behance from the extensions folder is what got rid of it. Next I want to get rid of "Save for Microsoft Office" the button that nobody ever clicked on ever.

Comment: There's an option to "Enable Extensions" that's what it was.... It allowed app connections to Kuler and Behance... Yeah.. removed in ewer versions  though.

Answer (score 4):

You have to delete:

```
C:\Programs Files\Adobe\Adobe Illustrator CC 2014\Contents\Windows\CEP\extensions\behance
```

---

NOTE: **The Behance Publish Service plug-in has been removed as of Illustrator CC 2015.3.1.**

https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/kb/behance-publish-service-plugin.html